# Как получить число с первым нулем

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как числам от 1 до 9 придать такой вид 01, 02, 03 с помощью php или javascript?

Comment: Вы, наверное, имели в виду _JavaScript_, а не _java_?

Comment: ага, ошибочка))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для форматированного вывода данных в **php** можно использовать функцию [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)

Пример:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{
  echo sprintf("number - %'.02d", $i).'<br>';
}
echo sprintf("number - %'.02d", 247).'<br>';
```

Результат:

```
number - 00
number - 01
number - 02
number - 03
number - 04
number - 05
number - 06
number - 07
number - 08
number - 09
number - 10
number - 11
number - 12
number - 13
number - 14
number - 15
number - 16
number - 17
number - 18
number - 19
number - 247
```

Answer (score 0):

В PHP есть оператор конкатенации:

```
$num = 1;
echo('0' . $num);
```

А в JavaScript вы можете в явном виде привести число к строке:

```
var num = 1;
console.log('0' + num.toString());
```

Comment: Если честно слабоват в языках, вот например у меня есть $as, которая равна 1,2,3,4,.... 12,13,14.... и как сделать чтоб к ней добавлялись нули от 1 до 9??

Comment: см. ответ @Visman

Answer (score -1):

Раз уж тут есть метка js, а все про js молчат, то:

```
function conv(n) {
  return ("0"+n).slice(-2);
}

[0,1,58,99,101].map(conv) == "00,01,58,99,01" // true
```

Обращаю внимание, что трёхзначное число обрезалось до двух последних знаков.

Comment: За что минус-то?

Comment: Скорее всего за странное решение :)

Даже `num > 9 ? num : '0' + num` будет работать гораздо правильноее

Comment: @vihtor, я предупредил, как оно работает. Добавление нуля в большинстве случаев надо для форматирование даты или времени, а там трёхзначных чисел не бывает, поэтому неправильным такое поведение назвать немного сложновато.

Comment: ну так вы предлагаете часть решения, то есть его нельзя просто взять и начать использовать. к нему нужно еще дописать условие, которое не будет давать на обработку функции `conv` числа больше 99. а это странное решение

Comment: @vihtor, в датах нет чисел больше 99. Даже больше 60 нет. И как бонус, можно обрезать год до двух знаков, если захочется (а если не захочется, то нет никаких причин вызывать её для года).

Comment: кто говорит о датах? помоему спросили о числах, числа могут быть любые и нужно решение, которое будет [работать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446744/179068) без всяких "если".

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27716/discussion-between-vihtor-and-qwertiy).